# How to execute a script in parallel in bash?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, bioinformatics

I have a folder containing files with extension **.bam**. I want to run following script simultaneously and create separate output for each input name and extension **.txt**

```
samtools depth -ab target_interval.bed 12345XX.bam > 12345XX.txt
```

this command is for single file. I want execute this code at once
I tried the following code

```
for i in *.bam; do
samtools depth -ab target_interval.bed $i.bam > $i.txt
done
```

but it does not work effectively

Comment: Why did you add the python flag to the question?

Comment: Take a look at other tools, like `sambamba`.

Comment: solution is important. @jpnadas

Comment: My point is, the question has nothing to do with python....

Comment: @jpnadas There are things do with python too. This is just a code which can be executed in any programming language including python.

Comment: why this question is down voted ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned the word 'parallel', you could also batch process these with [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).  Something like this ought to work:

```
parallel "samtools depth -ab target_interval.bed {} > {= s/\.bam/.txt/ =}" ::: *bam
```

Just be careful you have enough memory to process multiple BAMs at once like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.bam; do
samtools depth -ab target_interval.bed $i.bam > $i.txt &
sleep .5
done
```

Comment: Note that this creates files named `12345XX.bam.txt`.  You can use `${i%bam}txt` to fix that.

Comment: this does not work on the entire file. The output has break in between. What is significance of **sleep .5**

Answer (score 0):

```
# list all files matched with '*.bam' on separate lines
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.bam' |
# remove bam suffix from all the files
sed 's/\.bam$//' | 
# use `xargs` to parallelize execution on nproc codes
xargs -d$'\n' -n1 -P$(nproc) sh -c '
     samtools depth -ab target_interval.bed "$1".bam > "$1".txt' --
```

Answer (score 0):

using **Make**

```
BAMS=$(shell find . -type f -name "*.bam")
%.txt:%.bam
    samtools depth   -ab target_interval.bed $< > $@

all: $(BAMS:.bam=.txt)
```

invoke: `make -j 4`